# Questions related to a paper of Cowling-Haagerup and uniform lattices of $\mathrm{Sp}(1,n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, oa.operator-algebras, lattices, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading the following [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393695) of Cowling and Haagerup for my master’s thesis. I am new to this area so I am not very conversant. So I do apologize if the questions are silly.

Question 1. In the proof of Corollary 1.5, they have constructed $L\in \overline{A(G)}^\ast$ with the property that $\lVert L \rVert\leq 1$ and $L(u)=\Lambda_U$ if $u(x)=1$ for $x\in U$, which they say follows from an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem. I don’t understand how or which version of the Hahn-Banach theorem they are using.

My guess is they are using the Hahn-Banach extension theorem by considering the subspace $\overline{A(G)}$ say $X$, where $X$ is the subspace generated by the compactly supported functions taking value $1$ on $U$. However, I am not been able to find a precise solution.

Question 2. Using the fact $A(G)^{\ast}=VN(G)$ they consider an element $T$, that corresponds to $L$. Then they convolve $T$ with an element of $A_c(G)$ of compact support $K$. As $VN(G)$ is the weak operator topology closure in $B(L^²(G))$ of some space ( $\mathbb{C}(G)$ to be specific) I don’t understand what this convolution means, as $T$ may not appear to be a function from $G \to \mathbb{C}$.

Question 3. (Now asked elsewhere: [Cocompact lattices in $Sp(n, 1)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448749/cocompact-lattices-in-spn-1))

I will be really helpful with any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed, your Q3 is fairly unrelated to your other question(s). If you'd ask Q3 separately, people (including myself) could give possibly-useful answer. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, I asked the third question separately. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448749/cocompact-lattices-in-spn-1.