# Cocompact lattices in $\mathrm{Sp}(n, 1)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, oa.operator-algebras, lattices

This is a continuation from my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448742/questions-related-to-hahn-banach-theorem-and-uniform-lattices-of-sp1-n?noredirect=1#comment1159530_448742). I am reading the following [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393695) of Cowling-Haagerup, and I was wondering whether there are uniform lattices in $\mathrm{Sp}(n, 1)$. Is there some way to explicitly construct such lattices in $\mathrm{Sp}(n, 1)$?

Comment: Yes. You should read Witte-Morris' book "Introduction to arithmetic groups" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063

Comment: By a result of Borel-Harishchandra, it seems that arithmetric subgroups of semisimple groups are finite covolume. But I am not even sure whether $Sp(n, 1)$ is semisimple.

Comment: Yes, it is semisimple. And all semisimple Lie groups admit cocompact lattices (all noncompact ones also admit non-cocompact lattices).

Answer (score 3):

For large $n$, $Sp(n,1)$ is too large for $p$-adic devices to construct a co-compact (=uniform) discrete subgroup. But we can still use a device well-known to Siegel and before. Namely, let $F$ be a real quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$, and $Q$ the $(n+1)$-by-$(n+1)$ diagonal matrix with entries $Q_1,\ldots,Q_{n+1}$, taken from $F$. The critical assumption about the $Q_j$ is that at *one* of the real imbeddings of $F$, $Q_1,\ldots,Q_n$ are positive and $Q_{n+1}$ is negative, while at the other real imbedding *all* the $Q_j$ are positive. With $\mathbb H$ the Hamiltonian quaternions, let $B=\mathbb H\otimes_{\mathbb Q}F\approx \mathbb H\oplus \mathbb H$. That is, $Q$ is anisotropic at one real place. Then
$$
\{g\in GL_{n+1}(B):g^*Qg=Q\} \;\approx\; Sp(n,1) \times Sp(n+1)
$$
By the compactness of anisotropic quotients (treated in [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/cptness_aniso_quots.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/cptness_aniso_quots.pdf) for orthogonal groups, but the idea generalizes), letting $\mathfrak o$ be either the Epstein quaternion integers or Hurwitz quaternion integers,
$$
\Gamma \;=\; \{g\in GL_{n+1}(\mathfrak o):g^*Qg=Q\}
$$
gives a discrete quotient $\Gamma\backslash G$.

... oops! ... forgot to say, the compactness of the factor $Sp(n+1)$ implies that the projection of $\Gamma$ to the *first*, non-compact $Sp(n,1)$ is still discrete!!! And $Sp(n,1)$ modulo that projection is compact.